# How to notify server that client is closing connection

Tags: c, sockets, select, openssl

I have a server that is running a `select()` loop that sometimes continues blocking when the client closes the connection from its side.  The `select()` loop handles all other read/write operations correctly and sets the correct file descriptor in the `fd_set`, leading me to believe that it is not an issue with the file descriptor setup on the server-side.

The way I planned on handling the client closing the connection was to have the `select()` break due to activity on the socket (closing it from the client-side), see that the fd was set for that socket, and then try to read from it - and if the read returned 0, then close the connection.  However, because the `select()` doesn't always return when the client side closes the connection, there is no attempt to check the `fd_set` and subsequently try to read from the socket.

As a workaround, I implemented a "stop code" that the client writes to the server just before closing the connection, and this write causes the `select()` to break and the server reads the "stop code" and knows to close the socket.  The only problem with this solution is the "stop code" is an arbitrary string of bytes that could potentially appear in regular traffic, as the normal data being written can contain random strings that could potentially contain the "stop code".  Is there a better way to handle the client closing the connection from its end?  Or is the method I described the general "best practice"?

I think my issue has something to do with OpenSSL, as the connection in question is an OpenSSL tunnel, and it is the only file descriptor in the set giving me issues.

Comment: If the SSL client properly closes the connection it should send a `close_notify` alert before closing the transport.

Comment: Hmm, I call `SSL_shutdown()` prior to closing the connection, which is supposed to send the `close_notify` alert (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html).  I guess the next step is for me to figure out why the client is failing to send the alert or why the server is not receiving the alert.

Comment: @cmlink did you verify with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, that the alert is actually being sent out, and that OpenSSL is also sending a TCP `FIN` packet to the other party?

Comment: I haven't taken Wireshark to it yet, I was just checking out all of the SSL_shutdown return codes and error codes first.  It appears that the server is receiving the `close_notify` because the client's `SSL_shutdown()` returns 1, but the server's `SSL_shutdown` gives me an `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.  As suggested in your answer, I need to dig a little deeper into OpenSSL's quirks, but I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way I planned on handling the client closing the connection was to have the `select()` break due to activity on the socket (closing it from the client-side), see that the `fd` was set for that socket, and then try to read from it - and if the read returned 0, then close the connection. However, because the `select()` doesn't always return when the client side closes the connection, there is no attempt to check the `fd_set` and subsequently try to read from the socket.

Regardless of whether you are using SSL or not, `select()` can tell you when the socket is readable (has data available to read), and a **graceful** closure is a readable condition (a subsequent read operation reports 0 bytes read).  It is only **abnormal** disconnects that `select()` can't report (unless you use the `exceptfds` parameter, but even that is not always guaranteed).  The best way to handle abnormal disconnects is to simply use timeouts in your own code.  If you don't receive data from the client for awhile, just close the connection.  The client will have to send data periodically, such as a small heartbeat command, if it wants to stay connected.

Also, when using OpenSSL, if you are using the older `ssl_...` API functions (`ssl_new()`, `ssl_set_fd()`, `ssl_read()`, `ssl_write()`, etc), make sure you are NOT just blindly calling `select()` whenever you want, that you call it ONLY when OpenSSL tells you to (when an SSL read/write operation reports an `SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE)` error).  This is an area where alot of OpenSSL newbies tend to make the same mistake.  They try to use OpenSSL on top of pre-existing socket logic that waits for a readable notification before then reading data.  This is the wrong way to use the `ssl_...` API.  You are expected to ask OpenSSL to perform a read/write operation unconditionally, and then if it needs to wait for new data to arrive, or pending data to send out, it will tell you and you can then call `select()` accordingly before retrying the SSL read/write operation again.

On the other hand, if you are using the newer `bio_...` API functions (`bio_new()`, `bio_read()`, `bio_write()`, etc), you can take control of the underlying socket I/O and not let OpenSSL manage it for you, thus you can do whatever you want with `select()` (or any other socket API you want).

> As a workaround, I implemented a "stop code" that the client writes to the server just before closing the connection, and this write causes the `select()` to break and the server reads the "stop code" and knows to close the socket.

That is a very common approach in many Internet protocols, regardless of whether SSL is used or not.  It is a very distinct and explicit way for the client to say "I'm done" and both parties can then close their respective sockets.

> The only problem with this solution is the "stop code" is an arbitrary string of bytes that could potentially appear in regular traffic, as the normal data being written can contain random strings that could potentially contain the "stop code".

Then either your communication protocol is not designed properly, or your code is not processing the protocol correctly.  In a properly-designed and correctly-processed protocol, there will not be any such ambiguity.  There needs to be a clear distinction between the various commands that your protocol defines.  Your "stop code" would be one such command amongst other commands.  Random data in one command should not be mistakenly treated as a different command.  If you are experiencing that problem, you need to fix it.

Comment: This is a good answer, the only thing I might disagree with is the "stop code" being improperly designed.  Because TCP is stream-based, I think it could deliver pieces of a command in separate segments to the application - which if the segmentation occurred in the random data portion of the command and the random data delivered at the beginning of the next read began with the "stop code", it could be misinterpreted by the server as a "stop code" instead of a continuation of the previous command.  I haven't actually encountered this problem, but it was just a thought I had.

Comment: Only if the code is processing the individual segments by themselves instead of processing whole messages, like it should be. Network protocols, especially over streaming transports like TCP, require structured messaging, regardless of any segmentation performed underneath. If your protocol is designed correctly, and is being processed correctly, then the segmentation would be pieced back together and only whole messages processed. Random data would never be seen as a "stop code", only a valid "stop code" message would be. Every TCP app/library has to deal with this issue the correct way

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it answers my questions pretty directly.  For those curious, the problem actually ended up being that the quiet shutdown mode (SSL_CTX_set_quiet_shutdown) was being set, thus the client did not send the `close_notify` alert... so always remember to check your initialization if your shutdown isn't working properly :/